# How to process large JSON response from API with Reactor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

The API responses with a **JSON object that have an array of objects** like `{"items":[{...},{...},...],...` with the data we need to process. The problem is that the array **has + 1.000 objects**, and the endpoint is slow to response, so the streaming takes many seconds to fulfill, and with our “bloking” programming model using the *Apache HttpClient* to consume the endpoint and *Jackson* to serialize the response, we wait to get the full body to parse all the object that constains the array, instead of process each element when it comes, saving time a memory usage because once an element is processed, we can leave to the GC to free the memory used by the element.

How can I consume with the **Reactor project** the response while the data is coming? There is no problem to change the HTTP client and/or the serializer we are using. Also we are using Java 8 with Spring MVC with Spring 4.3, but we can move the project to the upcoming release of Spring.

*Note*: The endpoint is a third party API, a simple GET to an HTTP 1.1 server, we cannot make changes about how it works, like add pagination or something like that.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to your problem?, I'm facing the same problem with the response having an "items" and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: The refactor was frozen for now, so I couldn't test Spring 5 new WebClient library + Reactor :(

Answer (score 2):

This use case is supported on the upcoming Spring Web Reactive framework, currently available in [Spring Framework 5.0 M3](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/08/spring-framework-5-0-m3-released) and via start.spring.io when selecting Spring Boot 2.0 + Web Reactive dependency.

When you are using [Flux](https://projectreactor.io/core/docs/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) input parameter or return value, every step of the processing is async and non blocking, and Jackson is used to serialized each individual element in order to allow you to serializer/deserialize big and potentially finite stream of elements. In that case, Spring will take care of identifying individual JSON element in the array for deserialization or to add the `[`, `,`and `]` of the JSON array for serialization. This also allows to consume JSON streams like Twiter JSON API.

Please notice that as soon as Jackson will support async non-blocking processing, we will update Spring Framework 5 codecs to use that natively.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. So I need to use the `WebClient` from Spring instead of the _Apache HttpClient_ client or the old `RestTemplate`. Right? Something like `new WebClient(new ReactorHttpClientRequestFactory()).perform(HttpRequestBuilders.get("http://example.com"))...`